# how to change style of button on click and click on different button it should be change to default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have numbers of buttons, i want to change style of button on click event, but after click on another button that button style should be change to default...
i am fetching buttons from DB like

```
<table  class="table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Tables</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($tables as $table)
    <tr id="table">
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <button class="btn" >{{$table->table_no}} </button>
      </td>
     </tr>
     @endforeach
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

my script is:

```
$('#table button').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','green');
  });
```

problem is if i click different button background color of that button should be change to default, how can I get this?? plz help, than you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDs need to be unique so I removed the IDs from the rows.

I also moved the inline CSS to a stylesheet.

Your loop content should look like this now

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <button class="btn" >{{$table->table_no}} </button>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Example code

```js
$(function() {
  $('#table button').on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#table button').removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
#table th,td { text-align: center; }
.selected { background-color:green }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" class="table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Tables</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" >{{$table->table_no}} </button>
      </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" >{{$table->table_no}} </button>
      </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" >{{$table->table_no}} </button>
      </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" >{{$table->table_no}} </button>
      </td>
     </tr>

   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: thanks , but i dont know numbers of table, i am getting tables from database

Answer (score 1):

use add class & remove class.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_removeclass.asp

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon. Links to W3Schools doubly so.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only by `CSS`, add below into your style:

```
button { 
   background: grey;
}
button:active { 
   background: green;
}
```

Comment: That will only make them green while the button is depressed